# React.render in TypeScript for component with both props and state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I have a TypeScript TSX file with a React component like this:

```
interface IHiProps {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

interface IHiState {

}

class Hi extends __React.Component<IHiProps, IHiState> {
  // render…
}
```

How do I correctly render this component in TypeScript?

```
var hiComponent: __React.Component<IHiProps, IHiState>;
hiComponent = __React.render(__React.createElement(Hi), { a: "A", b: "B" }, document.body);
```

This fails me with *Argument of type 'typeof Hi' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentClass'*. I am using definitely typed files from [the DefinitelyTyped repository of Boris Yankov](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work when you change your class like this?

```
class Hi extends __React.Component<IHiProps, IHiState> {
  static propTypes: __React.ValidationMap<any> = {
    a: __React.PropTypes.string,
    b: __React.PropTypes.string
  }

  // render…
}
```

Also using `__React` is suspicious as it is internal variable of React.d.ts. In runtime there would not be such variable - if you would not create it. Consider rather using modules:

```
/// <reference path="/path/to/react.d.ts" />
import * as React from React;
```